# How to catch any file recursively

Tags: php, iterator, recursive-regex

The following code catches all files recursively in the php extension.

```
$paths = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($realPath), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$files = new \RegexIterator($paths, '/\.(?:php)$/', \RegexIterator::MATCH);

foreach($files as $file){
    ...
```

I want to get files from any extension.
I want something to replace it: `'/\.(?:php)$/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you just change

```
  /\.(?:php)$/
```

to

```
 /.*/
```

Comment: well is the problem that it is matching directories too or does it throw an error?  You might could also try this pattern to just match files /\.(?:[a-zA-Z]+)/

Comment: If the extension has numbers?

Comment: This /\.(?:[^.]+)/ Is better?

Comment: /\.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/  Will match anything like:  'hey.html', 'sup.p5hp', so any alpha numeric combination.  If you are worried about matching dirs then I would do a conditional to check for that in your loop instead of just relying on the name.   I mean, in reality $paths has matched everything so in your loop you could just check if the item is a dir and skip it.